# Get second level property value using reflection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, extension-methods

I wrote an extension method that get value of a property for an object.this is that code:

```
public static string GetValueFromProperty(this object obj, string Name)
{
    var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(Name);
    var propValue = prop != null ? (string)prop.GetValue(obj, null) : string.Empty;
    return propValue;
}
```

It works fine with first level properties.Now I have a problem. I want to get selected text of a drop down list and I call that methos like this:

```
string s = drp.GetValueFromProperty("SelectedItem.Text");
```

bute it does not return any thing.

How I can extend my extension method that return value from second level property( or in general form any level)?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to find a property named `SelectedItem.Text` , but this property does not exist on the given object (and never will, `.` is a reserved character that cannot appear in a property name)

You can parse your input, splitting each method by `.`, and chain your calls one after each other :

```
public static string GetValueFromProperty(this object obj, string Name)
{
  var methods = Name.Split('.');

  object current = obj;
  object result = null;
  foreach(var method in methods)
  {
    var prop = current.GetType().GetProperty(method);
    result = prop != null ? prop.GetValue(current, null) : null;
    current = result;
  }
  return result == null ? string.Empty : result.ToString();
}
```

Live example [here](http://ideone.com/hCcFru).

**Edit:**

A reciprocal setter metho would look very similar (I made it generic on the type of the property to be set) :

```
public static void SetValueFromProperty<T>(this object obj, string Name, T value)
{
  var methods = Name.Split('.');

  object current = obj;
  object result = null;
  PropertyInfo prop = null;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < methods.Length - 1  ; ++i)
  {
    var method = methods[i];
    prop = current.GetType().GetProperty(method);
    result = prop != null ? prop.GetValue(current, null) : null;
    current = result;
  }

  if(methods.Length > 0)
    prop = current.GetType().GetProperty(methods[methods.Length - 1]);
  if(null != prop)
      prop.SetValue(current, value, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine.Can you please add code for Set Value for these properties? thanks

Comment: Edited with the Setter. Note that I'm not checking that the passed string is conforming.

Answer (score 1):

Quick code (traverse down the tree):

```
public static string GetValueFromProperty(this object obj, string Name)
{
    string[] names = Name.Split('.');
    object currentObj = obj;
    string value = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        string name = names[i];
        PropertyInfo prop = currentObj.GetType().GetProperty(name);
        if (prop == null)
            break;
        object propValue = prop.GetValue(currentObj, null);
        if (propValue == null)
            break;
        if (i == names.Length - 1)
            value = (string)propValue;
        else
            currentObj = propValue;
    }
    return value ?? string.Empty;
}
```